# Scroll top button appear when at a certain height

Tags: javascript, dom

here's my issue:

My button ( button used to scroll to the top of the page ) must appear when my window is at the top of my "nav", here is the 2 method i tried, please tell me what i do wrong :

```
function retourTop(){
    let boutonScroll = document.querySelector("#btnScroll");
    let navbar = document.querySelector("header nav");
    
    
    
    if(document.body.scrollTop < navbar.getBoundingClientRect.y){
        boutonScroll.style.display = "block";
    }else{
        boutonScroll.style.display = "none";
    }
```

and the second :

```
function retourTop(){
    let boutonScroll = document.querySelector("#btnScroll");
    let navbar = document.querySelector("header nav");
    
    if(document.body.scrollTop < document.querySelector("header nav").getBoundingClientRect.y){
        boutonScroll.style.display = "block";
    }else{
        boutonScroll.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want the button to appear when user scrolls past the navbar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used element.offsetTop and window.scrollY (run code snippet)

```js
let button = document.querySelector("button");
let nav = document.querySelector("nav");

function toggle(display) {
  button.style.display = display;
}

window.addEventListener('scroll',function(e) {
  let navHeight = nav.offsetTop;
  let scrollHeight = window.scrollY;
  
  scrollHeight >= navHeight ? toggle("block") : toggle("none");
});

function back() {
  window.scrollTo(0,0);
}
```

```css
header {
  height: 200px;
  display: flex; 
  background: lightgray;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: gray;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}
div {
  height: 200vh;
  width: 100%;
}

button {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>Scroll Down</nav>
</header>
<div></div>
<button onclick="back()">Back to Top</button>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for tout hello, you guys are the best. Hope i will help the same way someone later.